# .data section annoying error with nasm

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm

I am trying to learn x86_64 linux assembly. But I have annoying problem while trying to assemble the assembly code

Here's the program

```
section .data
    str db "12.3",0
section .text
global _start
_start:
    mov rax, 60
    mov rdi, 0
    syscall
```

While trying to assemble this program nasm gives the error

```
[heman-pc 13]# nasm -f elf64 1.asm
1.asm:2: error: comma, colon, decorator or end of line expected after operand
```

I am not able to figure out what is wrong with 2nd line

Comment: `str` is being interpreted as an instruction ([Store Task Register](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/STR.html)). To avoid this place `:` after labels. Try `str:`